# How to make li items drop at mouse pointer

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a page that will allow Drag n Drop listview items from one div to another.

I have done moving an item from one to another, but I got stuck in moving an item within a div (i.e. changing position of the item)

The jquery code is shown below:

```
$("#taskAssigned").droppable({
            accept: "#wrapper_taskOpen li, #wrapper_taskAssigned li",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
            // accepts items from taskOpen
                if (ui.draggable.parent().parent().parent().attr("id") == "taskOpen") {
                    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($("#taskassignlist")).removeAttr("style").attr("style", "position:relative;");
                    var linkOffset = ui.draggable.find("a").offset();
                    ui.draggable.find("a").removeAttr("style").css({left:event.pageX - linkOffset.left, top:event.pageY - linkOffset.top});
                }
            // accept internal drops (change position of the stickynote)
                else if (ui.draggable.parent().parent().parent().attr("id") == "taskAssigned") {
                    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($("#taskassignlist")).removeAttr("style").attr("style", "position:relative;");
                    var linkOffset = ui.draggable.find("a").offset();
                    ui.draggable.find("a").removeAttr("style").css({left:event.pageX - linkOffset.left, top:event.pageY - linkOffset.top});
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML code:

```
        <div id="taskOpen">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h5>Open Tasks</h5>
            </div>                  
            <div id="wrapper_taskOpen">
                <ul id="taskopenlist" class="stickynote">
                    <li id="draggable">
                        <a href="#" id="pos">
                            <h3>Title #2</h3>
                            <p>Text Content #2</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="draggable">
                        <a href="#" id="pos1">
                            <h3>Title #3</h3>
                            <p>Text Content #3</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="taskAssigned">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h5>Assigned Tasks</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper_taskAssigned">
                <ul id="taskassignlist" class="stickynote">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="taskClosed">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
                <h5>Closed Tasks</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="wrapper_taskClosed">
                <ul id="taskcloselist" class="stickynote">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem I have http://jsfiddle.net/lightbringer/SDF4m/

I can move an item from Open Task to Assigned Task (changing position to the position of mouse pointer)
I would like to be able to move the tasks in Assigned Task to a different location within that div. However, my code seems to be inaccurate in determining the position, and sometimes it does not capture the droppable event.

If someone could help me on this one I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jsTree I highly recommend using it as a plugin for what you are doing.

Comment: @abc123 thanks for your comment. I took a look at demos for jsTree, however I don't think I need a tree structure, I just need to make the a tag within the li tag to move to the mouse pointer position when dropped.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at jQueryUI sortable (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

i have a standard pattern that i've been using recently.  it include a [save order] button and message slot.  you can drag the items around then click the save button to commit.

key elements include:
- the id on the  itself. this id is how the sortable keeps track of item ordering.
- use of sortable on the tbody
- threw in a generic ajax call to update display order on any table.

```
HTML / PHP
<a href='' id='saveorder' disabled='disabled' class='btn btn-info'>Save Order</a>
<span id='message'></span>

echo "<tbody>"; 
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo "<tr id='id_{$row['doccategoryid']}'>";
                 // middle of row
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</tbody>"; 


JQUERY
    $('#saveorder').click(function(event) {
        var order  = $("#list tbody").sortable("serialize");
        $('#message').html('Saving changes..'+order);

        var table   = 'doccategories';
        var tableid     = 'doccategoryid';
        var tableorder  = 'displayorder';
        var limit       = 1500;
        var page        = 1;

        var params = order+"&limit="+limit+"&page="+page+"&table="+table+"&tableid="+tableid+"&order="+tableorder;
        // console.log(params);

        $.post("/admin/update_displayorder.php", params, function(theResponse){
            // $('#message').html(theResponse);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#list tbody").sortable({
        opacity: 0.6,
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function() {
            $('#saveorder').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#message').html('Changes not saved');
            $('#message').css("color","red");
        }
    });

AJAX CALL
<?php
require_once(__DIR__."/../common/globals.php");

// must be logged in
if (!isloggedin() || !isadmin()) {
    echo 0;
    die;
}
session_write_close();  // done with session

$table        = $_POST['table'];
$tableid    = $_POST['tableid'];
$newOrder     = $_POST['id'];
$page         = $_POST['page'];
$per         = $_POST['limit'];
$order        = $_POST['order'];

$counter     = ($page-1) * $per + 1;

// echo "page: {$page} per: {$per} counter {$counter}";

  foreach ($newOrder as $recordIDValue) {
    $sdb->query  = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$order} = {$counter}
                    WHERE {$tableid} = " . (int) $recordIDValue;
    $sdb->firequery();
    $counter++;
    // echo "{$table} saving: {$id} = {$recordIDValue} :{$query} {$counter} ".mysql_error();
  }

echo ' '.$counter.' Changes were saved - refresh to update order column';
?>
```

Comment: Hi,I have taken a look in sortable previously. However I'd like the li items to act like stickynote, i.e. it can be dragged and dropped freely and will be sticked to the same position I drag it to.

Answer (score 0):

To position your droppables correctly you should subtract half of their width and height from the final coordinate:

```
var aTag = ui.draggable.find("a");
var linkOffset = aTag.offset();
aTag.removeAttr("style").css({left:event.pageX - linkOffset.left - aTag.width()/2, top:event.pageY - linkOffset.top - aTag.height()/2});
```

**DEMO**: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B6WBf/)